# How to get velocity in last n minutes

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to do the following to calculate work velocity:

```
SELECT (count(*) / 1) velocity FROM mutable 
  WHERE timestamp > DATE(NOW()-INTERVAL 1 minute)
```

However, this seems to be returning a false result. What is the issue here, and how would I correctly do this query?

Comment: A false result? Do you mean wrong result or do you get an error?

Comment: It gives the wrong result. I think it has to do with using the `DATE` function here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're wrapping the expression in `DATE()` which will return a timestamp that corresponds with the start of a day, i.e. `yyyy-mm-dd 00:00:00`. As such, your expression will change only daily.

You could use `DATE_SUB()` though:

```
timestamp > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 minute)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use `date()` you are converting the value to a date.  That seems odd when you are subtracting one minute.  If you want a count from the most recent minute, then try:

```
SELECT (count(*) / 1) as velocity
FROM mutable 
WHERE timestamp > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 minute);
```